# How to find the similar numbers in a list and set a value for each number present in the list?

Tags: python, list, loops, duplicates, pattern-matching

i have a list containing mobile numbers which i extracted from a text file and store them in a variable `ph_final`. Now i want to check the matching mobile numbers from the list and want to gave them value `"Repeated"` and `"unique"` for rest of the numbers. Also i write the phone numbers into the csv file. So, i want those values in a csv column parallel to the mobile number column.So, i want to store the values in "cat" variable so that i can write that variable in a csv file.I tried this:

```
ph_final=""
l2=[]
cat=""
ph_final=re.findall(r'\d{5}.\d{5}|[1-9]\d{9}', text)
l2.append(ph_final) 
for i in range(len(l2)-1):
    if(l2[i]==l2[i+1]):
        cat="Repeated"         
     else:
        cat="Unique"
```

but it only set the value "Repeated" for the second match element but i want to set the value repeated for both. Also there will be more then one number in one line. This is the output i got :

```
 Numbers        cat
 12345          unique
 87654          unique
 87654          repeated
 34562          unique
 87654          unique
 09567,127548   unique
 67548,127548   unique
```

Then i tried this one:

```
for i in range(len(l2)):
    if(l2.count(l2[i])>1):
        cat="Repeated"
    else:
        cat="unique"
```

It is better then the code i tried before but the problem in this is it never set the value repeated for the number that have duplicates. I want it also set value "repeated" for that number which have duplicates. Here is how i get final result from this code:

```
 Numbers        cat
 12345          unique
 87654          unique
 87654          repeated
 34562          unique
 87654          repeated
 09567,127548   unique
 67548,127548   unique
```

**So, i also wants the value of second element from the list i.e 87654 to be repeated and also the last one as it have one match.**

*Finally the whole point is i want to make a program which search the each mobile number in the list and when it find the number more than once it set the value "repeated" for that number and its matching numbers. How can i create that program?*

Anyone here with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter 

l = [10,11,12,10,10,11,13,12]
c = Counter(l)        
result = {k:'repeated' if v>1 else 'unique' for k,v in c.items()}
```

the result will be:

```
{10: 'repeated', 11: 'repeated', 12: 'repeated', 13: 'unique'}
```

also the `c` is a counter that counts all of the numbers:

```
In [4]: c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[4]: Counter({10: 3, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for the method, but my numbers are string type so it thows error: **TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'** and also i have write the mobile numbers into the csv file so i want the "repeated" and "unique" value stored in a csv column parallel to the mobile numbers.